# How to search Google Play and get package name from Android app

Tags: android, search, google-play

I am looking for a way (if possible) to search for apps from within my own app and then get the package name so I can link to it on Google play.

Anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: So, you want to find out what apps are on the device, then link to them on the Google Play store?

Comment: Negative.  I want to search for apps that are not installed on the device.

Comment: Hmm, I think you'll have a tough time doing that in an automated way.

Comment: Agreed...I was hoping someone had knowledge of an API or something...my only option is to place the burden on the users...I can hear the 1 star ratings already...

Comment: You can possibly use this to get the job done: http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/

Comment: Appears to be working (had to learn all about oAuth2.0 first though)...submit it as an answer and I'll mark it correct...Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments above, you can use this unofficial Android Market API open source project to perform searches on Google Play and extract package identifiers:

http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/